# Displaying posts by two category in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want posts that belong to 2 categories to be shown under my current posts, and the 2 categories must be determined by the current post that been displayed, so I write this code but not working, please help, tnx.

```
<?php

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
    $category_id2 = $categories[1]->cat_ID;
    $query = new WP_Query( array('category__and' => ($category_id, $category_id2),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',);
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

  ?>
```

Comment: You want post belongs to particular two categories(cat A, Cat B) or posts which belong to any categories but there should be 2 categories selected(means Cat A & cat B or Cat a 
 & cat c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws a `php error` because you forgot a `)` at the end.

This shoud work:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
$category_id2 = $categories[1]->cat_ID;
$query = new WP_Query(
 array(
 'category__and' => array( $category_id, $category_id2 ),
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'orderby' => 'publish_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
),
);
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

Try to use `wp_debug` in such cases

Comment: thanks for your help , yes that worked but it also need to remove ',' before last ')' for some reason that I dont know!